# Using a VLOOKUP in VBA - Taking Care of N/A's by referencing a different VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, vlookup

I am having trouble figuring out this IF-THEN statement in VBA. The code I'm using currently uses a VLOOKUP to pull values into Column E, but some results come in as #N/A because they are not contained the tab which the VLOOKUP is referencing. If a result comes in as #N/A, I need VBA to do another lookup (preferably Index/Match) on a different tab within my workbook. This is what I have so far, step 6 works perfect but returns some N/A's. The error is coming from step 7 as I am trying to address the N/A's with the IF-THEN statement:

```
'Step 6: Copy the recordset to Excel

 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DQ_Collectors_3162")
    .Activate
    .Range("A2:R" & Rows.Count).Clear
    .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    'Dealer column
    Dim dealerCol As String
    Dim FinalRow As Integer
    Dim contractCol As String


    contractCol = ConvertToLetter(FindMatchingValueColumn("Contract ID", 1))
    FinalRow = .Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    lookup = "=VLOOKUP(" & contractCol & ":" & contractCol & ",'Dealer Name 
    Index'!A:B,2,FALSE)"
    dealerCol = ConvertToLetter(FindMatchingValueColumn("Dealer", 1))
    .Range(dealerCol & "2").Value = vlookup
    .Range(dealerCol & "2:" & dealerCol & FinalRow).FillDown
    .Range(dealerCol & ":" & dealerCol).Copy

End With

'Step 7: Take Care of N/A's

    Dim R As Range
    indexmatch = "=INDEX('IBIC Name Index'B:B,match(B:B,'IBIC Name 
    Index'A:A,0))"

    Set R = Range("E:E")
    If R.Value = "#N/A" Then
    R.Value = indexmatch

End If
```

The error I'm getting is

> Run-Time error '13': Type Mismatch

Comment: Try using `R.Text` instead.

Comment: You are not going to be able to test the whole column at once like that.  You will need to set then end point and loop and test each cell individually.

Comment: Change step 6 to do step 7 as well?  e.g. `lookup = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & contractCol & ":" & contractCol & ",'Dealer Name Index'!A:B,2,FALSE),INDEX('IBIC Name Index'B:B,match(B:B,'IBIC Name Index'A:A,0)))"`  (P.S.  Should that variable be `lookup` or `vlookup`?  You might like to consider including `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code module.)

Comment: I didn't notice it was a range until I saw @ScottCraner comment. You can use this to test the whole range at once: `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(R,"#N/A")`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot look at an entire column and directly compare all of the cells to a single value the way you are trying. To deal with all of the #NA errors in column E, use SpecialCells.

```
Dim r As Range
With Worksheets("Sheet5")
    With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("E:E"))
        For Each r In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
            If r.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
                Debug.Print r.Address & " is an #NA error"
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test the entire range like this:

`If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(R,"#N/A") > 0 Then`